# WCF service with WIF AD Single sign on

Tags: wcf, authentication, active-directory, wif, adfs2.0

I have an Excel add-on which connects to a WCF endpoint located in our network to collect data. We're considering moving the application out to Windows Azure.

Currently the users are authenticated using their windows log on. I know that WIF, ACS and ADFS can allow us to authenticate on a web app but wondered if this would be possible with the WCF client.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: [Securing WCF Services with ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185912.aspx)

Also [ACS](http://acs.codeplex.com/) and the [code samples](http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples&referringTitle=Home) within.

If you are looking for delegation i.e. sign on using WIF and use that token for WCF, there's a delegation scenario and sample in the WIF SDK.